# Условие для json файла

Tags: python, json, vkontakte-api

Помогите написать условие, если делаю так при удачном отправлении выдает `req['response']` и получаю ошибку так как скрипт не может найти `req['error']['error_code']`
json ответ:

```
{'error': {'error_code': 14, 'error_msg': 'Captcha needed', 'request_params': [{'key': 'type', 'value': 'post'}, {'key': 'owner_id', 'value': '458306152'}, {'key': 'item_id', 'value': '4885'}, {'key': 'v', 'value': '5.131'}, {'key': 'expires_in', 'value': '0'}, {'key': 'method', 'value': 'likes.add'}, {'key': 'oauth', 'value': '1'}], 'captcha_sid': '458887933540', 'captcha_img': 'https://api.vk.com/captcha.php?sid=458887933540&s=1'}}
```

Код:

```py
url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/likes.add?type=%s&owner_id=%s&item_id=%s&v=5.131&access_token=%s' % (type_name, owner_id, item_id, token)
req = requests.post(url).json()
error = req['error']['error_code']
if error == 14:
   captcha_sid = req['error']['captcha_sid']
   captcha_img = req['error']['captcha_img']
   with open('newfile.jpg', 'wb') as target:
       a = requests.post(f'{captcha_img}')
       target.write(a.content)
   captcha_key = vc.solve(image='newfile.jpg')
   #print(captcha_key)
   url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/likes.add?captcha_sid=%s&captcha_key%s&type=%s&owner_id=%s&item_id=%s&v=5.131&access_token=%s' % (captcha_sid, captcha_key, type_name, owner_id, item_id, token)
   req = requests.post(url).json()
print(req)
```

Comment: Для начала исправьте табуляции

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try:
     if req != req['response']['likes']:
       continue
except:           
     error = req['error']['error_code']
     if error == 14:
        print("error")
```